# Create a new post in wordpress with XML-RPC with the correct GUID?

Tags: xml-rpc

When I use XML-RPC to create a new post instead of wp_insert_post the post is created with wrong guid/URL. With XML-RPC the guid is created with ID not slug.

```
// Input data
$my_page = array();
$my_page["post_title"] = $alternatename_main;
$my_page["post_content"] = $postcontent;
$my_page["post_excerpt"] = $postexcerpt;
$my_page["post_status"] = "publish";
$my_page["post_date"] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$my_page["post_author"] = 1;
$my_page['post_type'] = 'post';
$my_page["post_name"] = "test1234";

// Local insert
$my_page_id = wp_insert_post($my_page);
$wp_post_data = get_post($my_page_id);
$wp_guid = $wp_post_data->guid;
```

**Result: $wp_guid = http://test/site/test1234/**

```
// Insert XML-RPC
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-IXR.php' );
include_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-wp-http-ixr-client.php' );

$client = new WP_HTTP_IXR_Client('http://test/site/xmlrpc.php');

$client -> debug = true; //optional but useful

$username = "yyyyyy";
$password = "xxxxxx";
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$my_page);

$clientresult = $client->query('wp.newPost', $params);

$my_page_id = $client->getResponse();

$wp_guid = get_the_guid($my_page_id);
```

**Result: $wp_guid = http://test/site/?p=12721**

I have tested:

```
$wp_post_data = get_post($my_page_id);
$wp_slug = $wp_post_data->post_name;

$my_page_update = array();
$my_page_update["guid"] = "http://test/site/".$wp_slug."/";
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$my_page_id,$my_page_update);
$clientresult = $client->query('wp.editPost', $params);
```

But it doesn’t work.

The only solution I can find is to use raw sql:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid='"http://test/site/".$wp_slug."/"' WHERE ID=".$my_page_id .";
```

I cant see any reason why the post is created with different guid, both post are created with the correct slug. A bug in wp.newPost? Does anyone have a answer? The test is done on the same wordpress installation.

Comment: I think I got a solution, but it only works if$my_page["post_status"] = "publish";. It doesn’t work on draft.

Answer (score 1):

This is an annoying problem, but there is a way to get the correct link if I do:

```
$my_page_ask = array( 'link', 'guid' );
$params = array(0,$username,$password,$my_page_id, $my_page_ask);
$clientresult = $client->query('wp.getPost', $params);
$post = $client->getResponse();
```

The string link contains the correct permalink if:

```
$my_page["post_status"] = "publish";
```

It doesn’t work on draft and the string guid still contains the wrong value.